# How to register a custom test in Jinja2 (Flask)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In a website I'm building with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) I want to test if a variable is None. To my surprise though, something as simple as this doesn't work:

```
{% if my_var is not None %}
    {{ my_var }}
{% endif %}
```

this throws an error: `TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'None'`. So following [this example](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-tests), I wrote a simple custom test:

```
def is_none(var):
    if var is None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which I want to register in Flask as follows:

```
from jinja2 import environment
environment.tests['None'] = is_none
```

but this throws an error saying `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Or is the documentation simply wrong? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT] 
Okay, I got a bit further. I now register the test using this:

```
from jinja2 import Environment
environment = Environment()
environment.tests['None'] = is_none
```

but when I try to use it in my template, I still get the error saying `TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'None'`. Any ideas?

Comment: You could just use the [built in `none` test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#none).

Comment: as per flask docs, to register a jinja2 filter you need to have `app.jinja_env.filters['None'] = is_none` . Link to the doc : click [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/)

Comment: Yes @dirn is correct. You can use the builtin jinja2 filter

Comment: @dim - Awesome! I didn't notice that test, thanks a million! Could you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Nice Learnbit. Classifying this as a Jinja annoyance though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jinja has a [built-in test for `None` called `none`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#none).

```
{% if variable is none %}
    The variable is none. 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 18):

To register a **custom test**, use the following decorator:

```
@app.template_test("none")
def is_none(obj):
    return obj is None
```

Then you can use `is_none` as a test: `{% if my_var is none %}`. As dirn pointed out, this duplicates a builtin test, but I thought that I would answer your original question.

Documentation is at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.template_test

Comment: That is what I came for, and not for a specific answer like the accepted one. Thanks!